# What Grid Setup would you recommend

Tags: mysql, cdn

I have a web that currently runs off one Mediatemple VPS.  I'm now at the stage were the site is getting bogged down with scaling issues and I need to move to a better setup.

Is this a sensible setup:

php on one server
mysql database on another
Cloud Files CDN used to server images, javascript and css

My main thinking is to put the MySQL database on its own server away from the rest of the files as it seems to be causing most of the problems.

Comment: Seems like a great question for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the lowest hanging fruit by tackling the scaling problem that are easiest to resolve and don't involve hardware solutions. Identify the bottleneck that has the greatest effect on performance. If its your SQL server that is running slow and being funky, read the sql logs, and do some googling :).

Just make sure that your hardware is the problem and not your application.